# Triggering transparent image layers (.png) on top of a base image using hotspots on base image

Tags: css

I don't know where to start. I'm pretty confident there is a solution for what I would like to accomplish but that I may not be using the right terms when searching for help.

On the website that I am building for an Airline I would like to have an image of a map displayed.  The map/image will have several key locations (travel destinations) marked on the map.  The departure point on the map/image for each flight will be the same.  As a user moves the pointer of their mouse over a marked location I would like a track line (dotted line) that represents the flight path of the airplane appear between the departure point and the marked location selected. When the user moves their mouse pointer off the marked location the track line will disappear.

I thought I could use image mapping and have a hot spot behave in such a way that as I rolled over with the mouse a transparent image (containing my track line) would appear on top of my base map/image.  In addition to this effect I would also like a text box unique to the location to appear.  The text box wouldn't be very large but it would have a couple of lines containing some flight information for the location chosen.

I'm not sure where to start with this project.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I forgot to finish it last night. I also didn't get it working with pure css, although there is a way. This way works as well using

```
document.getElementById(yourid).style.opacity=1;
```

on hover. Basically it's a couple images stacked on top of each other.

[Link to example](http://jsfiddle.net/CPdrq/1/)